# Word for "induce someone to disavow an idea"

Tags: single-word-requests

What word would you use in the following context:

> We need to _____ him from the idea that he can buy it at that price.

I believe there's a word that exactly describes the idea of getting someone to abandon an idea, and I believe it starts with "dis-". Would "divorce" work in this context?

Comment: The word you're looking for is ***dissuade*** (persuade someone not to take a particular course of action), not ***disavow*** (deny responsibility or support for something).

Comment: @FumbleFingers +100 for dissuade

Answer (score 3):

Is the word you are looking for 'disabuse'?

The Free Dictionary defines it as:

> *tr.v.* **dis·a·bused, dis·a·bus·ing, dis·a·bus·es**
>
> To free from a falsehood or misconception.

It was the first that struck my mind, and is used for the exact very use.

[Thomas Hardy's  **Tess of the d'Urbervilles - A Pure Woman**    *Chapter XXX*](https://hardy.thefreelibrary.com/Tess-of-the-dUrbervilles--A-Pure-Woman/30-1#disabuse) features the usage of disabuse in a similar connotation, to give an example.

> "Well, it is for my convenience as well as my happiness. If I have a very large farm, either English or colonial, you will be invaluable as a wife to me; better than a woman out of the largest mansion in the country. So please--please, dear Tessy, disabuse your mind of the feeling that you will stand in my way."

If used, your sentence would now be;

> "We need to *disabuse* him from the idea that he can buy it at that
> price."

EDIT: Of course, **discourage** can also work equally well, as will **dissuade**. Other synonyms exist, of course, but do not fulfil your criteria.

Comment: A minor point: One generally *disabuses (someone) **of***, not *from* (as shown in the Hardy quote). So the example should be "We need to *disabuse* him *of* the idea that he can buy it at that price."

Comment: That's exactly it, I was looking for **disabuse**. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

disabuse is likely the word you are looking for bu another good one is **dissuade**:  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dissuade)

> To prevent (someone) from a purpose or course of action by persuasion